# issue in exporting from hive to vertica

Tags: sqoop, sqoop2

I am trying to export the data from mapr hive to Vertica. For this I have used the following sqoop command.

```
sqoop export  --driver com.vertica.jdbc.Driver --connect "jdbc:vertica://*****:5433/dbName" --username "******" --password "*****"  --export-dir maprfs:///marketing/hive/dbdata/test.db/test_tab --table test_table  --input-fields-terminated-by E'\001' -m 1
```

But i end up with following error:

```
cat: /opt/mapr/zookeeper/zookeeperversion: No such file or directory
Warning: /opt/mapr/sqoop/sqoop-1.4.6/bin/../../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: /opt/mapr/zookeeper/zookeeper- does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -XX:-UseLargePages
16/10/27 11:47:45 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-mapr-1601
16/10/27 11:47:45 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for export:
16/10/27 11:47:45 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -.password
16/10/27 11:47:45 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: *******
16/10/27 11:47:45 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --export-dir
16/10/27 11:47:45 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: /marketing/hive/dbdata/test.db/test_tab
16/10/27 11:47:45 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --table
16/10/27 11:47:45 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: test_table
16/10/27 11:47:45 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --input-fields-terminated-by
16/10/27 11:47:45 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: E\001
16/10/27 11:47:45 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -m
16/10/27 11:47:45 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: 1
```

could you please advise me how can we export the data to vertica using Sqoop
Thanks,
Bhaskar.

Comment: use `--password` instead of `-.password`

Comment: Aplogies I did that as well  --pasword  enven then also I was getting the above errors 16/10/27 11:55:01 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --password

Comment: don't use double quotes in username and password